# How to get a value input from html returned of cURL?

Tags: php, html, curl

I need to capture only the values of html inputs returned from curl_exec () function. This function returns the full html of the page, is there any way to take only the values of the inputs?

my code:

```
public function searchUser(Request $request){

    $data = $request->all();

      $cURL = curl_init('http://www.example.com/result.php');

      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      $dados = array(
        'num_cnpj' => $data['cnpj'],
        'botao' => 'Consultar'

      );
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);

      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/index.php');

      $result = curl_exec($cURL);

      curl_close($cURL);

    return $result;

}
```

Comment: There is no function which can help you with like this. You'll either need to write a parser which can get you those values or you can implement a rest api to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using one of the many PHP dom parsers.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

```
<?php
# Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Parse the HTML
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($result);

# Iterate over all the <input> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('input') as $input) {
        # Show the attribute value
        echo $input->getAttribute('value');
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but the method$dom->getElementsByTagName('input') is not capturing inputs, returning empty.

Comment: Oh sorry, my html was not returning inputs but a table with the results, changing the input tag for td and is now working. Thank you!